# Как скопировать текст элемента в его data-атрибут?

Tags: javascript, атрибуты

На сайте есть несколько элементов с классом `js-data-content`. Нужно придумать скрипт, который будет в каждом таком элементе брать его текстовый контент и вставлять его в атрибут data-content.

Например из:

```html
<a class="js-data-content" href="#">Текст</a>
<p class="js-data-content">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Сделать:

```html
<a class="js-data-content" href="#" data-content="Текст">Текст</a>
<p class="js-data-content" data-content="Lorem ipsum">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

1. Выбираем все элементы с классом `js-data-content` с помощью [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
2. Проходимся по всем элементам с помощью [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
3. Достаём именно **текстовое** содержимое с помощью [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
4. С помощью [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) устанавливаем значение аттрибуту `data-content`

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('.js-data-content')
  .forEach(element => {
    element.setAttribute('data-content', element.textContent);
  })
```

```html
<a class="js-data-content" href="#">Текст</a>
<p class="js-data-content">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: А если нужно будет ещё для другого класса `class="js-data-content-2"` то же действие добавить, то как проще это в скрипт прописать?

Comment: @Mitorun ```querySelectorAll('[class*=js-data-content]')```

Comment: @soledar10 лучше `querySelectorAll('[class^="js-data-content"]')`.

Comment: @Mitorun А от этого название аттрибута тоже будет меняться или название аттрибута будет одинаковым для всех?

Comment: @EzioMercer атрибут одинаковый, он для ховер-анимации, а класс чуть другой просто чтобы можно было разные анимации делать и не плодить лишние классы (хотя не проблема и с одним классом плюс модификатор).